# Wpf: Is it possible to bind an image to a viewModelProperty that is located in another project in the solution

Tags: wpf, vb.net, image

I have a multi project solution in which there is a project holding all the views and one holding the view models.  In the project holding the views I have a folder (imaginatively called 'Images')  which contains all of the images used in the various views.

Within one particular view I wish to have an image change dynamically at runtime so I have created a property of type System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage in that view's view model and bound the imagesource of a button in the view to that property in xaml.

```
  <!-- Login Button -->
            <ribbon:Button ImageSourceSmall="{Binding Path=SecurityImage}" />
```

in the constructor of the viewmodel I have the following:

```
SecurityImage = New BitmapImage(New Uri("/FtpViews/Images/security_lock16.png",UriKind.Relative))
```

FtpViews is the name of the project containing the views.

If I have the Images folder in the same project as the view model referecing it I can get this to work, but I can't seem to get the uri reference to work correctly if the images folder is in another project in the solution.  Either I have the notation of the Uri completely wrong (which is more that possible as I always seem to find that they are often a case of trial and error) or you can't actually reference resources in linked projects in this way.

I'd welcome any thoughts on this.

Thanks

Comment: Im using vectors not images, but in my case this is the path I would use. "/YourProjectName;componet/FtpViews/Images/security_lock16.png"

Comment: For reference, here is the [Resource File Pack URI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx#Resource_File_Pack_URIs___Local_Assembly) documentation on MSDN.

Comment: Thanks Clemens.  found out that I was almost there in the first place, should have been  SecurityImage = New BitmapImage(New Uri("/FtpViews;component/Images/security_lock16.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute))